# Ubuntu Studio / Dell XPS 9380 : failure

Tags: dell, kde, ubuntu-studio

I've recently tried to install Ubuntu Studio (23.10) on a Dell XPS 9380 : the installation worked (with some caveats, like a 6cm x 4.5cm installer guide because of a 3xxx*2xxx resolution ^^´) but the desktop was barely usable - if any.
There were way too much issues to list them all, and since I didn't have the time (still don't) to fix them all, I switched to kubuntu just to see if I could reproduce the issue within the source OS. Well, it's a lot better. A lot. Still had some minor issues at first, but it works reasonnably well.
For now my guess is that the low-latency kernel might be the issue with the laptop (audio was not working at all, among other things).

I still need Ubuntu Studio since the laptop is supposed to be used for everything related to music (ardour, jack etc) and I'm not fond of the idea to have to install every single app needed.

So for the question : I know I can use the ubuntustudio-installer.
Can you tell me please if there is any caveat I should know before using this installer instead of a plain ubuntu studio install ?